# Aws ACM - how does the verification of SSL cert in DNS work

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, aws-certificate-manager

Let's say I have created a public SSL cert in ACM and choose DNS validation.
After that, I will use this SSL cert in my Cloudfront Distribution.

I have just a fundamental knowledge of How DNS Server works.

From AWS.

> The Domain Name System (DNS) is a directory service for resources connected to a network. On the internet, DNS servers are used primarily to translate from domain names to the numerical IP addresses that identify and locate resources such as computers and other devices. The databases on DNS servers contain domain records that are used for this translation and to enable other functionality. For example, A records are a type of DNS record used to map domain names to IPV4 addresses. MX records are used to route email. NS records list all of the name servers for the domain.

> ACM uses CNAME (Canonical Name) records to validate that you own or control a domain. When you choose DNS validation, ACM provides you one or more CNAME records to insert into your DNS database. For example, if you request a certificate for the example.com domain with [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) as an additional name, ACM creates two CNAME records for you.

After the certificate request is sent, I need to add the DNS configuration of this cert in my DNS Record in order to verify the cert.

I am not sure what this step serves as.

1. What is the purpose of this step?
2. What will happen if I add this DNS configuration in other people's DNS record instead of mine?

**Update**

1.)
Sorry I know it seems a stupid question.
According to the comment, below situation would never happen?

my DNS Record

```
www.MyDomain.com.   A   123.120.110.1
```

Tom DNS Record

```
www.TomDomain.com.  A   123.120.110.1
```

2.)
Let's assume I help a client for the revamp of website ABC(domain name: https://example.com)
The client want to use the same domain name of website ABC.

After I finish the website, I created SSL certificate for the example.com and created a Cloudfront distribution for the build files.

The steps I should perform then:
a) provide the DNS configuration file obtained from SSL cert in ACM to client and let them add to their DNS Record.
b) add the SSL cert in my cloudfront Distribution.
c) the client add a CNAME record for https://example.com to point to cloudfront distribution domain name(d8abcbdbwbd.cloudfront.net etc)

Is it correct?

3.)
There is a SSL cert for domain myDomain.com.

my DNS Record

```
www.MyDomain.com.   A   123.120.110.1
```

Tom DNS Record

```
www.TomDomain.com.  A   123.120.110.2
```

If Tom add my SSL cert in his DNS Record, error will occur in his side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. What is the purpose of this step?

Your quote explains why you have to do this: `to validate that you own or control a domain`.

> 2. What will happen if I add this DNS configuration in other people's DNS record instead of mine?

SSL will not be issued as validation of the domain will fail. You can only validate the SSL if you own (or control) a domain, in which case you can explicitly add CNAME records that ACM will give you to use for validation.

Update:

1. If you control both `www.MyDomain.com` and `www.TomDomain.com` then you can point them to the same IP. Thus, such a setup is possible.
2. Yes. The CNAME generated by ACM for the verification will have to be added manually. Only if you use R53 to manage your domain, it can be added automatically. Also remember that the SSL must issued  in `us-east-1` region.
3. You can have different domains on a single certificate. Thus if you register both these domains for SSL, two CNAME records will be generated for verification and you will have to add these records to their respective domain for verification.

Below is example with your two sample domains:

[image]

Since I don't control any of them, after 72h, validation expires.

Comment: How does this step validate that I own or control a domain?

Comment: @CCCC Because if you don't control a domain, you can't add any records it. Otherwise, what would stop people from adding domains to, e.g., google.com. If this was the case, you could have your website on `http://cccc.google.com`, or `http://cccc.amazon.com`? Only if you control `google.com` you could add cccc record to it.

Comment: I updated the questions. Really appreciate for your help.

Comment: For update 1, so I can point www.MyDomain.com to the IP of google.com by creating a A Record?
For update 3, what would happen if you add this SSL cert to your DNS Record?

Comment: @CCCC 1. Yes, it can be any IP. But you won't be able to pretend that `www.MyDomain.com` is google as google will respond with redirection request as it will "see" that the request is not comming from google domain. And even if, the ssl certificats will be for google domian, and they would not match `www.MyDomain.com`. 3. I don't understand what you are asking. Add which ssl to what record?

Comment: I mean what will happen if u add the dns configuration of the ssl test you create above, in your own dns record

Comment: @CCCC The way it works is that to verify the domain, AWS will make request to, e.g., `_8ba487d74cb7e78ad151775c75f0de12.www.mydomain.com.` Since I don't own `www.mydomain.com`, a request to `www.mydomain.com` for record `_8ba487d74cb7e78ad151775c75f0de12` will fail because it won't exist. If I create `_8ba487d74cb7e78ad151775c75f0de12` in my domain, AWS will not care, it only queries `www.mydomain.com` for this record.